# How to get a detailed list of our comments

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
def comment_details(request, comment_id):
    comments = Comment.objects.all().filter(id=comment_id)
    context = { 
        'comments': comments,
    }
    return render(request, 'theme/comment_detail.html', context)
```

Its supposed to get the `id` from a comment, and write this comment in a separate `.html`. If I remove `comment_id` from both the expected argument, and from `filter(id=comment_id)` and write, for example, `id=24`, it will show the `24th` comment.

Please ask for anything needed, the HTML is as follows:

```
{% block container %}
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="container">
    <p>{{ comment.comment}}</p>
    <p>By: {{ comment.comment_by }}</p>
    <p>Published: {{ comment.comment_datetime }}</p>
```

```
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and the button that should make it print is here:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'comment_details' %}" details-id="{{comment.id}}"> More details</a></td>
```

Comment: Try converting it to int before you pass it to filter argument: `Comment.objects.all().filter(id=int(comment_id))` if you are saying this works for you `Comment.objects.all().filter(id=24)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you trying to do. You take an instance of Comment (why filter? comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_id) ) and then you loop over the single instance. I might be missing something, please explain little more if question still relevant.

Comment: I have a page with comments. For each comment I have a link which is supposed to lead to a detail page for that single comment. If I put in a random id like "(Comment.objects.all().filter(id=24)" all the links will be about comment 24.  So I thought if I could get the "comment_id" I could just put it in "(Comment.objects.all().filter(id=comment_id)". But I don't get it how I can do it. Like, I donno how a comment gets id=2 and so on.

Comment: Maybe it will become clearer if you show your `Comment`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, if you are looking up for a record by 'id', it means it is going to be a single record. So your query should be,

```
Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
```

You should validate if the record for the given id exists or not.

If you are looking for list of comments, than probably you have to look towards forming your query as such.

Then, you can simply return the queryset object and loop it in your template.

As of now, your piece of code is wrong.

Comment: I have a page with comments. For each comment I have a link which is supposed to lead to a detail page for that single comment. If I put in a random id like "(Comment.objects.all().filter(id=24)" all the links will be about comment 24. So I thought if I could get the "comment_id" I could just put it in "(Comment.objects.all().filter(id=comment_id)". But I don't get it how I can do it. Like, I donno how a comment gets id=2 and so on.